# ML model validation on skewed data

Tags: machine-learning

Say, I'm building a ML model to predict if a patient has flu or not. I know that, on average, only 2 out of 100 patients in the population have flu.

Usually, to estimate model's accuracy I just calculate what percentage of new data the model labels correctly:

```
accuracy rate = (correctly identified patients / total number of patients)
```

But in this case, I can write a model that labels all patients as not having flu and it will be accurate 98% of the time.

So probably the estimator should consider not only how much patients the model labeled correctly but also how much of the sick patient it actually found, something like

```
accuracy rate = (correctly identified patients / total number of patients) *
                (correctly identified patients with flu / total number of patient with flu)
```

But this estimator has no real-world interpretation.

Is it a right way to think about it and how would you calculate accuracy rate of a model on such a skewed data? Thanks!

Comment: You have just stumbled upon a *huge* subtopic called "class imbalance", where accuracy is indeed meaningless; start googling ruthlessly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to a balanced model, the *long answer* is "It depends", the *short-term* answer you can look into is something called the **Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC)** / **Phi-Value**.

As you saw, **Accuracy** is a really bad metric when facing imbalanced datasets. The MCC takes the size of classes into account and corrects for that. It delivers the same result for the the same model performance, no matter what the makeup of a dataset is.

- TP = Number of true positives
- TN = Number of true negatives
- FP = Number of false positives
- TN = Number of false negatives

`MCC = (TP * TN  - FP * FN) / sqrt((TP + FP)*(TP + FN)*(TN + FP)*(TN + FN))`

- MCC = 1 -> Perfect prediction
- MCC = 0 -> No correlation
- MCC = -1 -> Absolute contradiction

*Just from experience (in my field, therefore with a huuuuge grain of salt):

reasonable models for the companies I work with usually start around `MCC >= 0.75`*

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to use of MAP. And for it you need to calculate Recall and Precision:

Recall = (True Positive) / (True Positive + False Positive)

Precision = (True Positive) / (True Positive + False Negative)

- Positive: patient has flu
- Negative: patient has not flu
- True: correctly identified
- False: wrong identified